# Type specific java.util.List.toArray()

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
java.util.List<String> result = new java.util.LinkedList<>();
```

And have added some strings to it.

But I want to return a `String[]`. Ideally I'd like to write

`return (String[])result.toArray();`

But I get a casting error at runtime. (Cannot convert `Object[]` to `String[]`). Is there a way round this that doesn't involve manual element by element copy?

Comment: Use the overloaded method `toArray(T[] arr)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly for this there is the `toArray(T[] arr)` method so you can pass it a String array